# How can i loop through an array of objects in flutter

Tags: flutter, loops, dart

Here is my code

```
Future ppp() async {
    var url ='my url here';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    return response;
  }
   var data = await ppp();
   var id = json.decode(json.encode(data.body));
   print(id);
```

when i print, this is the result

```
[{"id":"168"}]
```

What i want to access is the 168

Answer (score 1):

```
var parsedJson = json.decode(json.encode(data.body));
var id = parsedJson[0]['id']
```

Dunno why you encode and decode body

Comment: am getting this error: Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Comment: var id = parsedJson[0]['id'].toString();

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var id = json.decode(json.encode(data.body));
print(id[0]["id"].toString());
```